# SQL Server stored procedure with parameter (for inputing image by path) not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a table that stores images as `varbinary`, and I want to create a stored procedure to insert images, by providing the path to the image.

But it's not working

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddImage 
    @ImagePath VARCHAR(255)
AS
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO Image(RawValue)
                    SELECT BulkColumn
                    FROM Openrowset(Bulk '+ @ImagePath +', Single_Blob) AS img';

    EXEC(@sql)
GO
```

When I try to execute it:

```
EXEC AddImage @ImagePath = 'C:\Users\[myname]\Desktop\wit4.jpg'
```

I run into the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
>   Incorrect syntax near 'mere'.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra pair of single quotes around the string:

```
SET @sql = '
        INSERT INTO 
            Image(RawValue)
        SELECT  BulkColumn
        FROM Openrowset(Bulk '''+ @ImagePath +''', Single_Blob) as img
';
```

I don't know if you could pass this in as a parameter.  If you could, I would strongly recommend doing that instead of munging the query string.

In SQL, you can put a single quote in a string by doubling it.  So, a string with a single single quote is represented as `''''`.  The two outer single quotes delimit the string.  The two inner single quotes define the single quote character.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, i wanna ask tho, why is it like that? what does it need 3?

Comment: Single quotes in a TSQL string literal need to be escaped, or else the string literal would be over.  And you escape a single quote by inserting two single quotes in the literal string.

Comment: Wouldn't QuoteName work here too: QuoteName (@ImagePath, '''')

Comment: @MarkKram . . . I would be careful with using `QUOTENAME()` on something that is not supposed to be an identifier.  The purpose of `QUOTENAME()` is to safely escape *identifiers* not generic strings.